# Highlight symbols and numbers with Highlight.js

Tags: javascript, highlight.js

I would like to use [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) library, ‏
and I am not able to highlight the `+` symbol and numbers (e.g. `1000`).‏
Is there anyway to do that?‏

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import hljs from 'highlight.js'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    hljs.registerLanguage("pl", function(hljs) {
      return {
        case_insensitive: false,
        keywords: {
        literal: '--',
        symbols: '+',
        keyword0: ' minus # plus   ++ $_  ',
       operator:' 1 2 3 4 /+ ',
       numbers: '/[0-9]+?/',
        keyword1: ' THEMENBEREICH ZEIT AUS BIS GIB HAT IST MAX MIN MIT TYP VAR VON'
        
        },
      contains: [
          {
            className: 'string',
            begin: "'",
          end: "'",
         // contains: [hljs.BACKSLASH_ESCAPE]
          },
          
      hljs.COMMENT(
            '"', // begin
            '"'  // end
      )
        ]
    };
    })

  }

  updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll("pre code").forEach(block => {
      hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
  };
  
handle(event){
    this.setState({
        data:event.target.value
  })
}

  render() {
    let eingabe = this.state.data
     return (
      <div>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="5" type="text"  onChange={this.handle.bind(this)}/>
        <br/>
        <button   onClick={this.updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting.bind(this)}>   clik   </button>
        <pre><code class="pl"> 
       
        {this.state.data} 
        </code></pre>
          
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Look up the documentation for `keywords.$pattern`... you have to set a regex to match keywords if you're using all sorts of weird characters... the default is `\w+`, which will only match `a-z_-`, etc... and you can't use regular expressions inside keywords, only strings. `+` isn't included in `\w` so it will never match as a keyword.  You may want to just consider multiple modes thought vs trying to do everything with keywords.

Comment: Oh `beginKeywords` might help you a lot also (inside of modes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make separate rules instead of using `keywords`.

```
contains: 
[
  { 
    className: "number",
    begin: /\d+/
  },
  {
    className: "symbol",
    begin: /+/
  }
]
```

Etc.

Or you could try `keywords.$pattern = /\S+/`, ie a keyword is any list of sequential characters that doesn't include a space...

https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-guide.html#keywords